# Saving and loading UITableView array - iOS Swift Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have the following; which fetches the data from the Parse backend and loads the class instances into a `NSArray` to plug into a `UITableView`.

```
var ObjectIDClass = PFQuery(className: "TestObject")

ObjectIDClass.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
  (ObjectsArray : [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  var ObjectIDs = ObjectsArray as! [PFObject]
  for i in 0...ObjectIDs.count-1 {
    self.iDArray.append(ObjectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
    self.NameArray.append(ObjectIDs[i].valueForKey("PDFName") as! String)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
})
```

This only works with network connection and as soon as the application is closed and then reopened without network, the table is blank. What I am aiming for is to store the data in the `Local Datastore` and if there is no connectivity, load from the `Local Datastore`. I can't figure it out using `pin`, but sure that is how it is done. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: **findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock** is an synchronous method so you must as connection to query data. what are you trying to do

Comment: I hope you meant `asynchronous` @Lamar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of focusing strictly on `Local Datastore`, which isn't a bad thing. I just feel you are using that solely because you want to have access to that data, say when the user is in airplane mode, or when there are just low network conditions. If that is the case, then you can take advantage of Parse's built in cache system. The `PFQuery` cache by default is set to ignore cache. This means, none of the information incoming from the server is stored in a temp folder on the users hard disk (exactly what your looking for). So you have to explicitly tell the objects to be cached on device using [one of their many caching policies](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/easy-caching-with-parse/)

For you, this will be good:

```
query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
// Results were successfully found, looking first on the
// disk and then on network.
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

You can review other ways to cache with these options : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-caching-queries

Small side note, please don't uppercase your variables. It doesn't follow proper naming conventions. `ObjectIdDClass` should resemble, somewhat, what your going to do with it's class, so it should be called `query` or something. And `ObjectsArray` should be `objects` because you already know it's an array and you don't capitalize anything that's not a class, usually. It makes for easier reading

Comment: Perfect thank you.  You're right I got fixated on localdatastore which, when looking at the documentation, didn't seem right for the purpose.   Thanks for the tips... I was taught that about 10 years ago and have since forgotten the conventions to follow! It does make it prettier

Comment: Great @Tom it's Stack Overflow etiquette to accept answers that resolve any outstanding issues within your question. If this does help, please accept the answer by selecting the check mark next to it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 I'm not really concerned with it, but other users who are working hard to earn rep would like to be praised. Additionally, it lets other users who have the same problem know that the answer is the right one that they should implement in their own project as well as reducing duplicate questions with same topics.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for explaining - appreciate your help and patience!